# Open existing reportings services in Business Intelligence Development Studio

Tags: reporting-services, business-intelligence

I've lost my Reporting Services project file for Business Intelligence Development Studio. How can I open the existing reports in a new project? Can I "open" the whole project like in SSAS? I want to get the datasets and data sources into the project again as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make a new solution and add your reports to it. there is no problem.

Comment: thank you. I thought there might be a way to get "all in one".